# php calling function dynamically with @ symbol

Tags: php, mysql

I want to call the **mysql_connect** function dynamically with the **@ symbol**, depending on if the user is an admin or not (to supress error messages):

```
//User is an admin:
mysql_connect(...)
//User is not an admin:
@mysql_connect(...)
```

I have tried this:

```
//MODE_ADMIN is true or false   
private static function mysql_connect(){
    return call_user_func_array((MODE_ADMIN ? '' : '@').'mysql_connect', func_get_args());
}
```

But I get this errror:

**call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function '@mysql_connect' not found or invalid function name**

So is there an easy way to call mysql_connect / @mysql_connect dynamically? Of course I coud do an if/else statement and passing each argument, but this wouldnt be nice.

*(Our databse was offline, a hardware failure, and the website was full of errors like 'mysql too many connections', even when the error reporting was E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE ^ E_WARNING ^ E_DEPRECATED).*

Thanks for hints.

Comment: @call_user_func_array maybe? Otherwise, you'll have to create a method alias and call mysql_connect in it. Then, you call this new method via call_user_func_array instead of mysql_connect

Comment: ok... so @call_user_func_array else call_user_func_array ...

Comment: Maybe just fix the problem rather than suppress the error message(s)?

Comment: *PSA:* The `mysql_*` functions are [deprecated in PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated). It is not recommended for writing new code as it will prevent you from upgrading in the future. Instead, use either [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Comment: The database was offline, not our fault, hardware failure.

Comment: What if instead of suppressing the error, you catch it?  Only show it if `MODE_ADMIN` is true.

Comment: Haw can i catch the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even more generic; you could do something like this and make it work for all functions:

```
<?php

define('IS_ADMIN', true);

class Dispatcher
{
    static public function __callStatic($func, $args)
    {
        if (defined('IS_ADMIN') && IS_ADMIN)
        {
            return @call_user_func_array($func, $args);
        }
        return call_user_func_array($func, $args);
    }
}

// now you can do these:
$mysql = Dispatcher::mysql_connect(...);
$passwd = Dispatcher::file_get_contents('/etc/passwd');
```

Comment: I appreciate all the other hints, but this is what I asked : )

Comment: note that I am just answering the question, not advocating the use of code like this. I'm just not judging. I can't think of any but who knows what kind of valid edge case to do this could exist?

Comment: Well next time I will see if error_reporting(0) will do the trick. But E_WARNING were disabled, and there still was a warning! Well...

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you're trying to achieve different errors/warnings level in dependence of user access level.
You better to do it with, for example, [error_reporting()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) - and do not use `@` symbol ever - cause it make debugging near impossible.

*Notices about deprecated **mysql** I prefer leave to comments above*

Comment: What do you mean? Setting `error_reporting(0)` will suppress any error messages, even fatal errors will not be shown.

Comment: error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE ^ E_WARNING ^ E_DEPRECATED) still gave me an mysql error message 'too many connections'.

Comment: My answer is exactly wnat you're going to do: set `error_reporting(0)` instead of `@` using (in general, that will have same effect).